# Update rails version 4.0.3 to 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

When i do bundle command i get the following:

```
You have requested:
rails = 4.2.0

The bundle currently has rails locked at 4.0.3.
Try running `bundle update rails`
```

then when i do "bundle update rails":

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 4.2.0) ruby

    rails (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
      actionmailer (= 4.2.0) ruby depends on
        rails-dom-testing (>= 1.0.5, ~> 1.0) ruby depends on
          activesupport (4.2.0.beta1)
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'

ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
```

I really don't understand that well what is going on. Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will also need to update the gem `rails-dom-testing` when you upgrade rails.

```
bundle update rails rails-dom-testing
```

Comment: uhmm i get "Could not find gem 'rails-dom-testing'."